# Workflow error when publishing

Tags: workflow

[image]I am trying to create a workflow in SharePoint Designer 2013. I am doing a simple get the date and time when an item is created. But, every time I try to publish it I get the following error.

> System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Specified argument was out of the
>   range of valid values. Parameter name: id    at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPTimeZoneCollection.GetTimeZoneInfoById(Int32
>   id)    at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.WorkflowServices.SPWebWorkflowSecurityContext.CreateOrUpdateServiceGroup(SPWeb
>   lookupWeb, SPAppPrincipal app)    at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.WorkflowServices.SPWebWorkflowSecurityContext.b__3()
>   at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSecurity.<>c__DisplayClass5.

Can anyone help guide me in troubleshooting this error? This is the first workflow to be created.

Answer (score 1):

In order to fix this problem I rebuilt the site. This time I added my user to the admin group on the local machine. And reran the workflow register code with the -force to connect the workflow to the site.

Answer (score 0):

I just did a workflow very similar to this. I'm not sure why it is throwing that particular error, but you can try my solution to see if it resolves it.

Another problem I see is that you want a time with the date, and the 'Today' argument only passes the date. The following statement doesn't use any workflow variables, and grabs both the date and time.

```
Set CurrentDate to Today 
then Set CurrentDate to Current Item:Modified
```

This assumes, of course, that CurrentDate is the field that you want the date stamp to appear in Sharepoint.

Comment: I edited my workflow to look the same as your's, and received the same error.I'm pretty sure that the problem isn't with the workflow. I think it is with how the SharePoint site is setup but i'm not sure what is wrong or how to fix it.

Comment: In Sharepoint Designer, when you go to create the workflow, there should be a little select box where you can select "Sharepoint 2013" or "Sharepoint 2010" workflow. Try it as a 2010 workflow. A while back, one of our guys got that error on our old server and this fixed it. This is more of a workaround, but we got it to work.

Comment: Changing the workflow to 2010 did let the process complete. However, I need the 2013 workflows to work.

Comment: I'm not sure about that, then. After completing the workaround, I never investigated this matter further. I hope I still managed to help in some way!